# Component not loading up on change of variable in *ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript

When loading variable changes to false, app-loadingspinner stops being displayed which is expected. But as per my understanding, at the same time app-paginator should start getting displayed which isn't happening. 
I suspect my understanding is incorrect. If so, how can we achieve the expected behaviour?

deals.component.html

```
<app-loadingspinner *ngIf="loading"></app-loadingspinner>
<div fxLayout="row" fxFlex.md="70" fxLayoutWrap class="card-deck-container mat-elevation-z4">
    <div fxFlex *ngFor="let deal of deals" class="card-item">
      <app-deals-card [ngStyle]="{'width':'300' + 'px'}" [deal]="deal"></app-deals-card>
    </div>
    <app-paginator *ngIf="!loading"></app-paginator>
</div>
```

deals.component.ts

```
export class Deals implements OnInit {
  public deals : Deal[] = []; 
  private next : string;
  private previous : string;
  loading = true;
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { 
    this.dataService.get_deals().subscribe((res : any[])=>{
      this.deals = res['results'];
      this.next = res['next'];
      this.previous = res['previous'];
      if (res instanceof HttpResponse){
          this.loading = false;
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: If you remove the `*ngIf="!loading"` from your **app-paginator** does it get displayed? Maybe the problem is not the `loading` variable.

Comment: yes, it get's displayed without  `*ngIf="!loading"`

Also, I just removed this check from ts file

`if (res instanceof HttpResponse)` and everything seems to work fine now. 
But I have no clue why it wasn't working and why it worked.

Answer (score 1):

the first thing I would look into is what does `this.dataService.get_deals()` return?
It should return an observable but will the type of the observable? 
will it always be an HttpResponse? (doesnt appear so)

Another suggestion I have is if you are using  the ngIf directive. If the goal is to check a boolean value and then display one of two components, maybe try to use the Angular DOM Marker.

```
<app-testing *ngIf = "loading; else showAppTester"></app-testing> 

<ng-template #showAppTester> 
<app-tester > </app-tester>
</ng-template>
```

loading is a boolean value i defined in the typescript that can be changed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion in the second paragraph, that was really a neat solution. 
Regarding the get_deals service(you can see the code below) I assumed it always returns observable of HttpResponse, not sure when It can observable of other types.

`return this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl + '/custom/deals/?limit='+limit+'&offset='+offset);`